# how to Generate a selector using JQUERY of Current Element $(this)?

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors

My requirement is that when user move  mouse on an element 
I want to get the selector of that element.
let say my current element is the  $(this)
and $(this) does not have any class and ID.
now I want grab the reference of this element later by a JQUERY
or CSS Selector. Note : limitation is that I can not assign $(element) 
any id or class.

if You visit femtoo.com for monitoring a web page.
i want the highlighted selector in the below picture.
my requirement exactly similar to this.
any Help please I am new in Jquery.
[image]

Comment: i got the reference of this. but  I do not know how to generate the
selector. it is fine if $(this) having an #Id but what if it does not
have Id and Uniqe class name then i want generate the selector which help to identify this help later.

Comment: can you please visit femtoo.com ?
in femtoo user comes  select an element like firebug then femtoo
generate the CSS selector of that element like shown in the above picture.

Comment: I just want Generate the CSS or Jquery Selector of current $(this)
element. Please share any Idea ? thanks

Comment: Can you use this http://api.jquery.com/selector/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to traverse the DOM tree up from a node to the root element, but it's not easy to create an unambiguous selector if an element doesn't have an ID attribute.

You haven't posted any code so you shouldn't really expect a solution, but I've done something like this before and may post it here.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/N7Rrh/2/

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var node = e.target, 
        parents = [], 
        selector = [];

        /* Build a list of ancestors up to the documentElement */
        while( node.parentNode ){
             parents.push( node );
             node = node.parentNode;
        }

    /* go over the ancestors list in reverse order, skipping the last two (HTML and BODY elements).
      use i = parents.length - 2 to include the BODY element. */
    for( var i = parents.length - 3; i >= 0; i-- ){
        var nodename, id, classname, siblings, index, selectorstring;
        // assign currently processed element to the node variable
        node = parents[i];
        // get the tag name, make it lowercase
        nodename = node.nodeName.toLowerCase();
        // if given node has an id let's use it as it's the best choice
        if( node.id ){
             selectorstring = nodename + '#' + node.id;   
        }
        // otherwise get as much info as needed
        else {
            // class name:
            classname = node.className
                        // remove leading and trailing white space
                        .replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g,'') 
                        // replace remaining spaces with dots
                        .replace(/\s+/g,'.');

            // nth-child / first child. 
            // get all the siblings  (children of parent node) 
            // and turn the nodeList to an Array
            siblings = [].slice.call( parents[i+1].children );
            // ... and find current node in that array
            index = siblings.indexOf( node );
            // now combine the info:
            selectorstring = nodename +
                            // add leading dot to the class name if there's a class name
                            (classname != '' ? '.' + classname : '') +
                            // append first-child or nth-child(n) string
                            (index===0?':first-child':':nth-child('+index+')');
        }
        selector.push( selectorstring );
    }
    // now join the selectors of particular elements as direct child selectors
    selector = selector.join('>');
    console.log( selector );
    return selector;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any event handler may be focus here.. you will get the dom reference of that textbox in the var `this` you can then call jQuery passing this like

```
$(this);
```

Answer (score -1):

Without applying any class :-

```
 $(this).css('border','solid 1px red');
```